# Evento on click repetindo a ação

Tags: javascript, jquery

Meu código:

```
var calendar = {

    init: function(org_id) {

             $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:8000/listar/' + org_id,
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json'
            }).done(function(data) {
                var events = data.events;

                for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
                    $('.list').append('<div class="day-event" style="text-align: center;" date-day="'+
                     events[i].day +'" date-month="' +
                     events[i].month +'" date-year="'+ events[i].year +'" data-number="'+ 
                     i +'"><h4>' + events[i].orgao + '</h4><h2 class="title">'+
                      events[i].title +'</h2><p>Das ' + events[i].inicio + ' ás ' + events[i].fim +
                     '</p><p>'+ events[i].description +'</p></div>');
                }

                // start calendar
                calendar.startCalendar();

            }).fail(function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                });


    },

    startCalendar: function() {
        var mon = 'Seg';
        var tue = 'Ter';
        var wed = 'Qua';
        var thur = 'Qui';
        var fri = 'Sex';
        var sat = 'Sab';
        var sund = 'Dom';

        /**
         * Get current date
         */
        var d = new Date();     
        var yearNumber = (new Date).getFullYear();
        var strDate = yearNumber + "/" + (d.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + d.getDate();


        // custom
        var tmpDate = new Date(strDate);
        var firstDay = tmpDate.getDay();
        var firstDisplay = true;


        var monthNumber = d.getMonth() + 1;


        function GetMonthName(monthNumber) {
            var months = ['Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro'];
            return months[monthNumber - 1];
        }

        setMonth(monthNumber, mon, tue, wed, thur, fri, sat, sund);

        function setMonth(monthNumber, mon, tue, wed, thur, fri, sat, sund) {
            $('.month').text(GetMonthName(monthNumber) + ' ' + yearNumber);
            $('.month').attr('data-month', monthNumber);
            printDateNumber(monthNumber, mon, tue, wed, thur, fri, sat, sund);
        }




        $('.btn-next').on('click', function(e) {            
            var monthNumber = $('.month').attr('data-month');
            console.log(monthNumber);
            if (monthNumber > 11) {
                $('.month').attr('data-month', '0');
                var monthNumber = $('.month').attr('data-month');
                yearNumber = yearNumber + 1;
                setMonth(parseInt(monthNumber) + 1, mon, tue, wed, thur, fri, sat, sund);
            } else {
                setMonth(parseInt(monthNumber) + 1, mon, tue, wed, thur, fri, sat, sund);
            };
        });


        $('.btn-prev').on('click', function(e) {            
            var monthNumber = $('.month').attr('data-month');
            if (monthNumber < 2) {
                $('.month').attr('data-month', '13');
                var monthNumber = $('.month').attr('data-month');
                yearNumber = yearNumber - 1;
                setMonth(parseInt(monthNumber) - 1, mon, tue, wed, thur, fri, sat, sund);
            } else {
                setMonth(parseInt(monthNumber) - 1, mon, tue, wed, thur, fri, sat, sund);
            };
        });





        /**
         * Get all dates for current month
         */

        function printDateNumber(monthNumber, mon, tue, wed, thur, fri, sat, sund) {

            tmpDate = new Date(yearNumber, monthNumber - 1, 1);
            firstDay = tmpDate.getDay() - 1;

            $($('tbody.event-calendar tr')).each(function(index) {
                $(this).empty();
            });

            $($('thead.event-days tr')).each(function(index) {
                $(this).empty();
            });

            function getDaysInMonth(month, year) {
                var date = new Date(year, month, 1);
                var days = [];
                while (date.getMonth() === month) {
                    var tmpArr = [];
                    tmpArr[0] = date.getDate();
                    tmpArr[1] = date.getDay();
                    days.push(tmpArr);              
                    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
                }   

                return days;
            }

            // function getDaysInMonth(month, year) {
            //  // Since no month has fewer than 28 days
            //  var date = new Date(year, month, 1);
            //  var days = [];
            //  while (date.getMonth() === month) {
            //      days.push(new Date(date));
            //      date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
            //  }
            //  return days;
            // }

            i = 0;

            setDaysInOrder(mon, tue, wed, thur, fri, sat, sund);

            function setDaysInOrder(mon, tue, wed, thur, fri, sat, sund) {
                firstDisplay = true;
                var monthDay = getDaysInMonth(monthNumber - 1, yearNumber)[0].toString().substring(0, 3);
                $('thead.event-days tr').append('<td>' + sund + '</td><td>' + mon + '</td><td>' + tue + '</td><td>' + wed + '</td><td>' + thur + '</td><td>' + fri + '</td><td>' + sat + '</td>');
            };


            $(getDaysInMonth(monthNumber - 1, yearNumber)).each(function(index) {
                var day = $(this)[0];
                var week = $(this)[1];
                var index = index + 1;


                if(firstDisplay == true){
                    for (var i = 0; i <= firstDay; i++) {
                        $('tbody.event-calendar tr.1').append('<td date-month="' + '' + '" date-day="' + '' + '" date-year="' + '' + '"><a href="#">' + '' + '</a></td>');
                    };
                    firstDisplay = false;
                }

                $('tbody.event-calendar tr.1').append('<td date-month="' + monthNumber + '" date-day="' + index + '" date-year="' + yearNumber + '"><a href="#">' + index + '</a></td>');
            });


            // function setDaysInOrder(mon, tue, wed, thur, fri, sat, sund) {
            //  var monthDay = getDaysInMonth(monthNumber - 1, yearNumber)[0].toString().substring(0, 3);
            //  console.log('===' + monthDay);
            //  if (monthDay === 'Mon') {
            //      $('thead.event-days tr').append('<td>' + mon + '</td><td>' + tue + '</td><td>' + wed + '</td><td>' + thur + '</td><td>' + fri + '</td><td>' + sat + '</td><td>' + sund + '</td>');
            //  } else if (monthDay === 'Tue') {
            //      $('thead.event-days tr').append('<td>' + tue + '</td><td>' + wed + '</td><td>' + thur + '</td><td>' + fri + '</td><td>' + sat + '</td><td>' + sund + '</td><td>' + mon + '</td>');
            //  } else if (monthDay === 'Wed') {
            //      $('thead.event-days tr').append('<td>' + wed + '</td><td>' + thur + '</td><td>' + fri + '</td><td>' + sat + '</td><td>' + sund + '</td><td>' + mon + '</td><td>' + tue + '</td>');
            //  } else if (monthDay === 'Thu') {
            //      $('thead.event-days tr').append('<td>' + thur + '</td><td>' + fri + '</td><td>' + sat + '</td><td>' + sund + '</td><td>' + mon + '</td><td>' + tue + '</td><td>' + wed + '</td>');
            //  } else if (monthDay === 'Fri') {
            //      $('thead.event-days tr').append('<td>' + fri + '</td><td>' + sat + '</td><td>' + sund + '</td><td>' + mon + '</td><td>' + tue + '</td><td>' + wed + '</td><td>' + thur + '</td>');
            //  } else if (monthDay === 'Sat') {
            //      $('thead.event-days tr').append('<td>' + sat + '</td><td>' + sund + '</td><td>' + mon + '</td><td>' + tue + '</td><td>' + wed + '</td><td>' + thur + '</td><td>' + fri + '</td>');
            //  } else if (monthDay === 'Sun') {
            //      $('thead.event-days tr').append('<td>' + sund + '</td><td>' + mon + '</td><td>' + tue + '</td><td>' + wed + '</td><td>' + thur + '</td><td>' + fri + '</td><td>' + sat + '</td>');
            //  }
            // };


            // $(getDaysInMonth(monthNumber - 1, yearNumber)).each(function(index) {
            //  var index = index + 1;
            //  if (index < 8) {
            //      $('tbody.event-calendar tr.1').append('<td date-month="' + monthNumber + '" date-day="' + index + '" date-year="' + yearNumber + '">' + index + '</td>');
            //  } else if (index < 15) {
            //      $('tbody.event-calendar tr.2').append('<td date-month="' + monthNumber + '" date-day="' + index + '" date-year="' + yearNumber + '">' + index + '</td>');
            //  } else if (index < 22) {
            //      $('tbody.event-calendar tr.3').append('<td date-month="' + monthNumber + '" date-day="' + index + '" date-year="' + yearNumber + '">' + index + '</td>');
            //  } else if (index < 29) {
            //      $('tbody.event-calendar tr.4').append('<td date-month="' + monthNumber + '" date-day="' + index + '" date-year="' + yearNumber + '">' + index + '</td>');
            //  } else if (index < 32) {
            //      $('tbody.event-calendar tr.5').append('<td date-month="' + monthNumber + '" date-day="' + index + '" date-year="' + yearNumber + '">' + index + '</td>');
            //  }
            //  i++;
            // });


            var date = new Date();
            var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
            var thisyear = new Date().getFullYear();
            setCurrentDay(month, thisyear);
            setEvent();
            displayEvent();         
        }

        /**
         * Get current day and set as '.current-day'
         */
        function setCurrentDay(month, year) {
            var viewMonth = $('.month').attr('data-month');
            var eventYear = $('.event-days').attr('date-year');
            if (parseInt(year) === yearNumber) {
                if (parseInt(month) === parseInt(viewMonth)) {
                    $('tbody.event-calendar td[date-day="' + d.getDate() + '"]').addClass('current-day');
                }
            }
        };

        /**
         * Add class '.active' on calendar date
         */
        $('tbody td').on('click', function(e) {
            if ($(this).hasClass('event')) {
                $('tbody.event-calendar td').removeClass('active');
                $(this).addClass('active');
            } else {
                $('tbody.event-calendar td').removeClass('active');
            };
        });

        /**
         * Add '.event' class to all days that has an event
         */
        function setEvent() {           
            $('.day-event').each(function(i) {
                var eventMonth = $(this).attr('date-month');
                var eventDay = $(this).attr('date-day');
                var eventYear = $(this).attr('date-year');
                var eventClass = $(this).attr('event-class');
                if (eventClass === undefined) eventClass = 'event';
                else eventClass = 'event ' + eventClass;

                if (parseInt(eventYear) === yearNumber) {
                    $('tbody.event-calendar tr td[date-month="' + eventMonth + '"][date-day="' + eventDay + '"]').addClass(eventClass);
                }
            });
        };

        /**
         * Get current day on click in calendar
         * and find day-event to display
         */
        function displayEvent() {           
            $('tbody.event-calendar td').on('click', function(e) {              
                $('.day-event').slideUp('fast');
                var monthEvent = $(this).attr('date-month');
                var dayEvent = $(this).text();
                $('.day-event[date-month="' + monthEvent + '"][date-day="' + dayEvent + '"]').slideDown('fast');
            });
        };

        /**
         * Close day-event
         */
        $('.close').on('click', function(e) {
            $(this).parent().slideUp('fast');
        });

        /**
         * Save & Remove to/from personal list
         */
        $('.save').click(function() {
            if (this.checked) {
                $(this).next().text('Remove from personal list');
                var eventHtml = $(this).closest('.day-event').html();
                var eventMonth = $(this).closest('.day-event').attr('date-month');
                var eventDay = $(this).closest('.day-event').attr('date-day');
                var eventNumber = $(this).closest('.day-event').attr('data-number');
                $('.person-list').append('<div class="day" date-month="' + eventMonth + '" date-day="' + eventDay + '" data-number="' + eventNumber + '" style="display:none;">' + eventHtml + '</div>');
                $('.day[date-month="' + eventMonth + '"][date-day="' + eventDay + '"]').slideDown('fast');
                $('.day').find('.close').remove();
                $('.day').find('.save').removeClass('save').addClass('remove');
                $('.day').find('.remove').next().addClass('hidden-print');
                remove();
                sortlist();
            } else {
                $(this).next().text('Save to personal list');
                var eventMonth = $(this).closest('.day-event').attr('date-month');
                var eventDay = $(this).closest('.day-event').attr('date-day');
                var eventNumber = $(this).closest('.day-event').attr('data-number');
                $('.day[date-month="' + eventMonth + '"][date-day="' + eventDay + '"][data-number="' + eventNumber + '"]').slideUp('slow');
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('.day[date-month="' + eventMonth + '"][date-day="' + eventDay + '"][data-number="' + eventNumber + '"]').remove();
                }, 1500);
            }
        });

        function remove() {
            $('.remove').click(function() {
                if (this.checked) {
                    $(this).next().text('Remove from personal list');
                    var eventMonth = $(this).closest('.day').attr('date-month');
                    var eventDay = $(this).closest('.day').attr('date-day');
                    var eventNumber = $(this).closest('.day').attr('data-number');
                    $('.day[date-month="' + eventMonth + '"][date-day="' + eventDay + '"][data-number="' + eventNumber + '"]').slideUp('slow');
                    $('.day-event[date-month="' + eventMonth + '"][date-day="' + eventDay + '"][data-number="' + eventNumber + '"]').find('.save').attr('checked', false);
                    $('.day-event[date-month="' + eventMonth + '"][date-day="' + eventDay + '"][data-number="' + eventNumber + '"]').find('span').text('Save to personal list');
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $('.day[date-month="' + eventMonth + '"][date-day="' + eventDay + '"][data-number="' + eventNumber + '"]').remove();
                    }, 1500);
                }
            });
        }

        /**
         * Sort personal list
         */
        function sortlist() {
            var personList = $('.person-list');

            personList.find('.day').sort(function(a, b) {
                return +a.getAttribute('date-day') - +b.getAttribute('date-day');
            }).appendTo(personList);
        }

        /**
         * Print button
         */
        $('.print-btn').click(function() {
            window.print();
        });
  }

};
```

Consigo exibir a agenda default sem problemas.
Mas quando mudo o órgão no select e modifico o mês usando o evento click:

```
$('.btn-next').on('click', function(e) {            
            var monthNumber = $('.month').attr('data-month');
            console.log(monthNumber);
            if (monthNumber > 11) {
                $('.month').attr('data-month', '0');
                var monthNumber = $('.month').attr('data-month');
                yearNumber = yearNumber + 1;
                setMonth(parseInt(monthNumber) + 1, mon, tue, wed, thur, fri, sat, sund);
            } else {
                setMonth(parseInt(monthNumber) + 1, mon, tue, wed, thur, fri, sat, sund);
            };
        });


        $('.btn-prev').on('click', function(e) {            
            var monthNumber = $('.month').attr('data-month');
            if (monthNumber < 2) {
                $('.month').attr('data-month', '13');
                var monthNumber = $('.month').attr('data-month');
                yearNumber = yearNumber - 1;
                setMonth(parseInt(monthNumber) - 1, mon, tue, wed, thur, fri, sat, sund);
            } else {
                setMonth(parseInt(monthNumber) - 1, mon, tue, wed, thur, fri, sat, sund);
            };
        });
```

O evento click funciona mas se repete. Por exemplo: Estou em dezembro/2016 e clico para Janeiro ele exibe Fevereiro/2017. Debugando vi que ele executa duas vezes o evento click.

O código para exibir a "agenda" via select está assim:

```
$("#sel-sec-org").on('change', function () {
        $('.list').empty();
        var agendaOrgao = $("#sel-sec-org").val();
        calendar.init(agendaOrgao);
    });
```

Quando inicia a aplicação é executado:

```
calendar.init(agendaOrgao);
```

Quando modifico o select para selecionar outro órgão ele executa novamente:

```
calendar.init(agendaOrgao);
```

Como prevenir que não seja executado o on click duas vezes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você deve "agendar" o evento em um bloco de código que só vai executar uma vez. Aparentemente você está fazendo isso dentro de outro evento que é disparado varias vezes. Nesse caso, o evento não é sobrescrito e sim enfileirado.

Uma solução seria adicionar um `.unbind( "click" )`, removendo assim o evento adicionado anteriormente. Dessa forma:

```
 ...
 $('.btn-next').unbind( "click" ).on('click', function(e) {            
            var monthNumber = $('.month').attr('data-month');
            console.log(monthNumber);
            if (monthNumber > 11) {
 ...
```

Mas isso apenas no caso de você realmente precisar redefinir o evento `click`.

Comment: Resolveu. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Tenta isso antes de adicionar os eventos de click:

```
$("#foo").unbind("click");
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!